# Can't get HTML from GET request

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a HTML code which is probably dynamically generated. The only thing I'm trying to is to get a html code of the next page. If you click on the button, everything works perfect of course. But if you check the href of this page and just copy paste it into your browsers address form and submit, you get a text which seems like this:

```
{"paging":{"isLastPage":false},"pagination":{"firstUrl":"/sk/komponenty/aktivne-prvky/analogove-obvody/spustacie-obvody/c/cat-L3D_525255/showmore?q=*&amp;filter_Buyable=1&amp;filter_Category4=Sp%C3%BA%C5%A1%C5%A5acie+obvody&amp;filter_Category3=Anal%C3%B3gov%C3%A9+obvody&amp;useTechnicalView=true&amp;pageSize=10&amp;page=1","prevUrl":"/sk/komponenty/aktivne-prvky/analogove-obvody/spustacie-obvody/c/cat-L3D_525255/showmore?
```

The same thing happens when you try to do a request with it's headers.

The thing is that I want to get a HTML code of the page you get when you click on the next page button down here: `http://www.distrelec.sk/sk/komponenty/aktivne-prvky/analogove-obvody/spustacie-obvody/c/cat-L3D_525255`

do you know how to get a HTML code?

EDIT: I've tried to find a GET which calls the next page and use requests module to simulate the click (with all request headers) but I got the same result. No HTML.

Comment: At the URL you included, the next page button links to [this URL](http://www.distrelec.sk/sk/komponenty/aktivne-prvky/analogove-obvody/spustacie-obvody/c/cat-L3D_525255?pageSize=10&page=2), which seems to be another HTML page. Anyway, it looks like you could just append `?pageSize=36&page=N` to the URL, but replace N with numbers 1,2,3,etc until there aren't any more results. That way, you don't have to mess with the next page button directly.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your result as well. The href refers to /sk/komponenty/aktivne-prvky/analogove-obvody/spustacie-obvody/c/cat-L3D_525255?pageSize=10&page=2. What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your getting the JSON which probably helps generate the dynamically the next page. If you just want to see the html of the next page, just right click and select "Inspect Element", in Google Chrome anyways, after the page loads.

But if you want the URL of the next page, inside the JSON it references the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't produce the JSON result, but this worked for me using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = #that url
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# this gives you the specific next link
next_link_tags = soup.find_all('a','btn btn-right js-page-link')
next_link_url = "http://www.distrelec.sk" + next_link_tags[0]['href']

html2 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(next_link_url))
print html2
```

Comment: This does not work. The soup of the link does not contains those tags. Another thing is that 'btn btn-right js-page-link'  is not a one class. It's mulstiple classes which BS can't handle this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how HTML of page 2 is formed. 
[image]
The secret is not just to *get JSON* of 'content 2' but also *to properly insert it* (replace with it 'content 1') into main HTML. Sure, the certain JavaScript is responsible for decoding JSON and updating/replacing content. 
You need:

- find it out what functions work to replace 'content 1' into 'content 2' (thru examining HTML and js-scripts) and what particulary they do.
- have your original HTML
- get JSON (as you've done)
- simulate replacement of original HTML as string with any python/other language means. Use regex for this. Or if you can make HTML a DOM structure, use XPath.

You sure have lots of jobs. Being an expert in JS. :-)